# How to make CheckBox dynamically in custom base class and how to get the checked valus?

Tags: android

I want to invite my friends, so i created a layout; in that layout I put an EditText and a CheckBox.
If I have 10 friends, it means that the friends name should be shown in the EditText, then I will check the CheckBox and in the next Activity I will get the checked friends names only.
How can I do this?

Comment: you can do this by custom listview much easier i would recommend